# Named predicates

Tags: java, lambda

I have a class that verifies a private member variable matches some conditions passed in as predicates

```
public class Verifiable<T> {
  private final T t;

  private Verifiable(T t) {
    this.t = t;
  }

  public static <T> Verifiable<T> of(T objToBeVerified) {
    return new Verifiable<T>(objToBeVerified);
  }

  public List<Predicate<T> verify(List<Predicate<T>> predicates) {
    // test against each predicate and return the failed predicates
  }
}

Usage:
  List<Predicate<T>> predicatesToTest = ...
  List<Predicate<T>> failedPredicates = Verifiable.of(someObj).verify(predicatesToTest);
```

I would like to print the failed predicates, in particular what the predicate was testing. I can achieve this by creating instances of an class, say NamedPredicate, that implementats Predicate. This class can hold a member variable called "name". There are at least 2 limitations with this approach: can't pass in lambda expressions, and the need to create instances of NamedPredicate.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you using Java7, or Java8?

Comment: @AmirAfghani I think Java8, he spoke about lambda :) @partheinstein Why not using an argument `Map<String, Predicate<T>>` in `verify(...)` instead of `List<NamedPredicate<T>>` ?

Comment: @Nizil Thanks. Post it as an answer and I mark it so. Another option is to use list of tuples (String, Predicate<T>). On a site note, Scala has has built-in support for tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you need to bind a `String` to a `Predicate`

1) Create something like a tuple, it's the idea behind your `NamedPredicate`.

```
public class NamedPredicate<T> {
  Predicate<T> predicate ;
  String name ;
}
```

Please always favorize encapsulation over inheritance, and avoids such class

```
public class NamedPredicate<T> extends Predicate<T> {
  String name ;
}
```

2) Use a `Map`. `Map<String, Predicate<T>>` should do the trick but you maybe can use a `Map<Predicate<T>, String>` depends on your architecture.

```
public List<Predicate<T> verify(Map<String, Predicate<T>> predicates) {
  List<Predicate<T>> failed = new ArrayList<>();
  for( String name : predicates.keySet() ){
    System.out.println("Testing "+name+" on "+t);
    // test predicates.get(name), add failed test to failed list.
  }
  return failed ;
}
```

Comment: If you want to go functional all the way, you can do   predicates.values().stream.filter(predicate -> !predicate.test(t)) to get a stream of failed predicates.